# How to use Java packages with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jar, sum

I'm at school and we are doing this java stuff. We use a special library named sum.kern: http://www.mg-werl.de/sum/bjw.zip

I want to use Groovy instead of Java. But I can't get groovy to use this library. If I add the jar in grape and try to import sum.kern and create a sum.kern.Bildschirm it says that it is not able to find it. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it should be a problem, its pretty straight forward. The only requirement is to have the library in your classpath.

Are you able to import the package successfully?

It doesn't matter though, What IDE are you using, BTW?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a "groovy-starter.conf" file that specifies the directories in which groovy looks for jar files.  It should be in the "conf" directory within groovy.home (for example, on my machine it is "C:\groovy\Groovy-1.5.6\conf\groovy-starter.conf").

If the jar file containing the classes you want to import are within one of these directories, you should be able to import it no problem.  Alternatively, you could add the directory that the jar is currently in to your groovy-starter.conf file.